# Proximity search, Sending Email to a few receiver

Tags: php, mysql, email, search, proximity

I have emails and street addresses stored in a MySQL database.  I want to use PHP to run a proximity/geospatial search and send an email to all the results within a given radius.

I can get the Email/Addresses in a foreach loop, but now I don't know how to send the email to all the results within the query result.

My code is like this:

```
foreach ($Ergebnis as $Eintrag) {
            echo '<li><strong>' . htmlentities($Eintrag->Name) . '</strong><br />' . "\n";
            echo htmlentities($Eintrag->Email) . '<br />' . "\n";
            echo htmlentities($Eintrag->Strasse) . '<br />' . "\n";
            echo htmlentities($Eintrag->PLZ) . ' ' . htmlentities($Eintrag->Ort) . '<br />' . "\n";
            if (!empty($Eintrag->Website)) {
                echo 'Website: <a href="' . $Eintrag->Website . '">' . htmlentities($Eintrag->Website) . '</a><br />' . "\n";   
            }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question not clear what you want to do... please describe more your effort......@Habibo

Comment: I'm creating a radius Search

It can be read from the database name, email, ......

Now I wanted to send an email to all displayed e-mail addresses.

hope u understand now what i want to do

Comment: @Habibo I think what ajeet meant is that it is not completely clear what you are asking. The first part of the question (including the title) sounds like you want to know how to do a proximity search (and didn't include what you did there so far). Only in the end it sounds like that you INSTEAD want to know how to send emails via php. For this though more information is needed. What type of email server are you using. Do you want to use php functions there or some library you have, ... and additionally what did you try there so far to send mails and why does it not work, ...

Comment: Okay.. I try again.
first I create a radius search ... the results are okay the funkction too.

Now i want that the user can send an email to all of the person that will show up in the radius.

that means 1 email to x receiver.

I get the Email addresses from the Database in the foreach loop.

now i want to get the array with the Email Addresses and make them as receiver for the Email Fomular, but i dont know how i can do that. 

Hope now it is clear.

thanks